# I keep getting this mysql error code #1089

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `movies`.`movie`
( `movie_id` INT(3) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `movie_name` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `movie_embedded_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL, `rating_no` INT(3) NULL,
  `movie_description` VARCHAR(50) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`(3))) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I keep getting this error:

> #1089 - Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't
>   support unique prefix keys.

but I've got no idea what it means, anyone have a clue?

Comment: Its probably this `PRIMARY KEY (\`movie_id\`(3))` change it to `PRIMARY KEY (\`movie_id\`)`

Comment: For me, i will just save it without having primary key. Once you save it, just edit the table at structure

Answer (score 124, accepted):

With the part

```
PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`(3))
```

you are telling mysql to create a **sub part key*** on the first 3 Bytes of movie id. This only works for string types.

You need to use

```
PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`)
```

without providing a length.

*Is this sure the query resulting in the error? Never saw that on a primary key, its used for indexes.

Comment: thank you very much, i didn't realise this was what i was requesting.

Answer (score 26):

after selecting PRIMARY KEY when you create table, don't input any value in pop dialog

Comment: You gave the exact solution what we need. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can also get this error when creating an index if you specify a prefix length that is longer than the length of the actual column.  If you tried to create an index containing `someColumn(20)` but in the table *someColumn* is `VARCHAR(15)`, then this error will occur.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error, after create in new tab with id column which I want to set 11 length as int type. I just edited and run manually the generated query for creating table then it is created.
Old version like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `demo_db`.`products` 
(
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
`note` VARCHAR(1500) NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`(11))
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Then I updated as follow

```
CREATE TABLE `demo_db`.`products` 
(
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
`name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
`note` VARCHAR(1500) NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the primary key do not enter any length of type.

```
Example:
int()
```