# mysql table creating error #1089

Tags: mysql, sql

We want to create a table in mysql DB but it's not working properly.

Error message showing:

> **#1089 -Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys**

This is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE `student_billing`.`payment` (
`id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`student_name` INT(255) NOT NULL ,
`student_roll` INT(255) NOT NULL ,
`student_batch_id` INT(255) NOT NULL ,
`student_course_name` INT(255) NOT NULL ,
`student_paid_ammount` INT(255) NOT NULL ,
`student_paid_date` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL , 
`student_payment_recivedby` INT(255) NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`(10))) ENGINE = MyISAM COMMENT = 'Students Billing DB';
```

Comment: Always remember to Google first! Googling the error message shows e.g. this, which may already be the solution to the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406066/i-keep-getting-this-mysql-error-code-1089

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### /*DDL Information*/

```
CREATE TABLE `payment` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_name` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_roll` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_batch_id` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_course_name` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_paid_ammount` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_paid_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `student_payment_recivedby` INT(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Students Billing DB'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the length of your field when declaring the PRIMARY KEY. Try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE `student_billing`.`payment` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_name` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_roll` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_batch_id` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_course_name` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_paid_ammount` INT(255) NOT NULL,
  `student_paid_date` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  `student_payment_recivedby` INT(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM COMMENT='Students Billing DB';
```