# Difficulty in creating a table in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have tried creating a table manually in mysql database with columns id, phone, email, password, paymwnt. Here id is the PRIMARY KEY auto increment but when I click save, the following error message displays

> incorrect prefix key. The used part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part or storage engine does not support unique prefix keys"

Someone please help.

Comment: What are the tool you are using? Can you show your table definition (as `create table ......`) or you are just using the program to do it?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/30406166/3583859

Comment: Please provide your script

Comment: Im creating it manually from the phpmyadmin using the tool not code

Comment: So, provide the table definition.

Comment: Provide the snapshot the tool with data feeded in it, that might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #USER_TABLE 
(
Userid int PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1), 
Last_Name varchar(50), 
First_Name varchar(50)
);
select * from #USER_TABLE
insert into #USER_TABLE values('k','Raj')
```

### Sol:

```
Userid  Last_Name   First_Name
1           k         Raj
```

Answer (score 0):

'payment' is float?

Please, try:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , phone VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL , email VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL , password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL , payment FLOAT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

> If possible, please respond with your full mysql query so I check the
>   error.