# Getting wrong response in volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am getting wrong response in volley while on the other hand postman getting correct response. Please help me where is the problem . Response i am getting from volley is "response= {"code":1020,"message":"Duplicate key not allowed","returnId":null}"
And in postman it is "{
    "code": 1089,"message": "Activation Key sent in email, please activate your user/device","returnId": 438
}"

```
public void sendRegisterationReq("http://demo.innowi.com/v1/user/register",getJsonObject()) {



        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);



        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url, dataObj,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        // Toast.makeText(context, "" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println("response= " + response.toString());
                        System.out.println(TAG + ":" + dataObj.toString());
                        try {
                            if (response.getString("code").equals("1020")){

                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterDeviceActivity.this,ActivateDeviceActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                String message = null;
                if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
                    message = "Network error!";
                    Log.d(TAG,message);


                } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                    message = "Server error!!";
                    Log.d(TAG,message);

                } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                    message = "Auth failure error!";
                    Log.d(TAG,message);

                } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
                    message = "Parsing error!";
                    Log.d(TAG,message);

                } else if (volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                    message = "No connection error!";
                    Log.d(TAG,message);

                } else if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    message = "timeout error !";
                    Log.d(TAG,message);

                }



            /*Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(TAG + ":Error: " + volleyError.getMessage());
            System.out.println(TAG + ":" + volleyError.toString());*/
                System.out.println(TAG + ":" + dataObj.toString());

            }
        }) {

            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             * */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }


        };
        jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);

        jsonObjReq.setTag("myRequest");
        // Adding request to request queue

        queue.add(jsonObjReq);



    }

public JSONObject getJsonObject(){

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    try {
        if (username!=null && password !=null) {
            object.put("username", username.getText().toString());
            object.put("password", password.getText().toString());
            object.put("deviceMacAddress", "90:B6:86:0D:CE:4F");

        }
        else
        {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Email/password should not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are the data which is already exist in your database so says duplicate key try different one or try to send all fields valid and different.

Comment: yeah i did this but getting the same response.

Comment: hey, I searched and get this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406066/i-keep-getting-this-mysql-error-code-1089  and add tags of databases that you are using.