# how to create table in phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

CREATE TABLE `newsportal`.`tbladmin` ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`AdminUserName` VARCHAR(11) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL , `AdminPassword` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL , `AdminEmailId` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL , `userType` INT(11) NOT NULL , `CreationDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , `UpdationDate` TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`(11)), INDEX `AdminUserName` (`AdminUserName`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

#1089 - Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys

I get this error instead of the table been created

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I keep getting this mysql error code #1089](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406066/i-keep-getting-this-mysql-error-code-1089)

Answer (score 1):

For the primary key do not enter any length of type.

Instead of

```
PRIMARY KEY (id(11))
```

do

```
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

By adding a length you're trying to create a `key_part`.

MySQL Reference Manual:

```
create_definition: {INDEX | KEY} [index_name] [index_type] (key_part,...)
```